# Encontrar una palabra en un archivo txt con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo txt, hay una columna con una palabra y luego el resultado seria algo asi:

```
Objetos    Descuento   Resultado
Casa       5           100000                
Puerta     20          150
Mesa       50          600
```

Si yo le digo al programa Casa me dira el resultado de casa, 100000

De momento solo tengo esto

```
 k = open("fact.txt","r")
    k.readline()
    codigo = input("Objeto: ")

    for l in k:
        Listalinia = l.split()
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres hacer, ¿podrías explicarlo mejor? ¿Las tres columnas de tu primer ejemplo se encuentran en el txt? ¿La columna Descuento y sus números la quieres ignorar?

Comment: Es un programa que le digo un objeto y te da el resultado, el descuento de momento nada, las columnas estan en fact.txt

Comment: Deberías considerar el leerlo como un archivo csv con delimitador de espacio/tabulador. Otra opcion es convertir el archivo a un json. No entiendo por qué querrías mantener esa pequeña base de datos en un archivo .txt, te puede dar problemas a la larga.

Comment: Claero pero es solo para un momento y a la larga usarlo en .csv pero hay manera de hacerlo en txt.?

Comment: ¿Pueden haber items con espacios? Por ejemplo `Cama Queen` o `Silla de terraza`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hubiera estado bien que nos dijeras cual es el problema con el que te encuentras ya que al menos parece que vas encaminado.

Uno de los problemas que veo en el código es que no cierras el fichero. Al final deberías llamar a `k.close()`

También puedes utilizar `with` que lo cerrará automáticamente por ti incluso si el programa falla!

```
with open('fact.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Skip header line
    line = file.readline()
    while line:
        line = file.readline()
        print(line)
```

Ya solo queda sacar la columna que te interesa. Hay varias formas de hacerlo, una de ellas es utilizando `split` otra sería utilizar expresiones regulares.

Cuando se está empezando suele ser muy útil ver el contenido de las variables con las que estamos trabajando.

Si empezamos con el caso del split:

```
print(line.split())
```

Vemos que eso nos devuelve algo así:

```
['Casa', '5', '100000']
['Puerta', '20', '150']
['Mesa', '50', '600']
[]
```

Con esto vemos que tenemos en la posición `0` el valor a buscar y en la posición `2` el valor a devolver. En python podemos asignar cada posición de un array a una variable de la siguiente forma:

```
while line:
    line = file.readline()

    search, _, returnValue = line.split()

    print(search, returnValue)
```

(Ignoremos el error `ValueError` por ahora)

Por último nos queda implementar la lógica para que cuando leamos la línea con el objeto que buscamos devuelva dicho valor.

Y nos quedaría algo así:

```
with open('fact.txt', 'r') as file:
    # Skip header line
    line = file.readline()
    to_search = input("Object to search: ")
    while line:
        line = file.readline()

        search, _, value = line.split()

        if search == to_search:
            print(search, value)
            break
```

En este caso el `break` es una pequeña optimización para no seguir leyendo el fichero si ya hemos encontrado lo que buscábamos.

Sin embargo si ponemos un item  que no existe tendremos un error como este:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 0)
```

El error viene de la línea `search, _, value = line.split()` y sucede cuando la línea está vacía ya que intentamos acceder a una posición del array que no existe.

Podemos manejar dicho caso de la siguiente forma:

```
    line = file.readline()

    if line == '':
        continue
```

Así como `break` hace que salgamos del bucle, `continue` hace que pasemos directamente a la siguiente iteración

Comment: Si la primera linea de tu txt es *Objetos    Descuento   Resultado* puedes usar *line=line[1:]* para omitirla